# Import PS3 saves for dragon age 2 after hdd exchange?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-2

I have a lot of savegames in Dragon Age 2 on my PS3. Because the HDD was just 80gb and new ones are pretty cheap, I just bought a new one.
I changed the HDD and am able to run Dragon Age 2 just fine.

The problem is, I am now unable to load any of my older saves. I copied them using the PS3 Save Game utility from XMB.

What can I do?

Comment: It is the same physical PS3. Does changing the HDD change the system guid?

Comment: According to the second answer of the linked question, no.

Comment: You would have to put back the old HDD, back it up, put the new one in and restore the backup.

Comment: How do I do that? I used the "Saved Data Utility" from XMB, is that not enough?

Comment: [This might help you](http://www.ehow.com/how_10016055_install-game-saves-through-ps3-xmb.html)

Comment: It think your problem maybe because you're using a different account on the new PS3. If the account used to create the save was associated with an PSN id the account used to load it will need to associated with the same PSN id. If the account wasn't associated with a PSN id, I think it gets assigned a sequential local id. If you had created more than one user account before try creating multiple local accounts and see if any of them can load the game.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this with a single PS3 is to backup your saves onto media outside of the PS3.  If Dragon Age 2 allows it, you could save them on a USB stick, swap the hard drives, and then copy them back over.

If the saves are encrypted, or won't allow you to transfer them onto a USB, your only option is to use PS Plus.  Back up the saves to the cloud, swap the hard drives, and download the saves.

If you're using the same PS3, it's that easy.  If you're moving the saves onto a different PS3, I believe uploading the saves to PS Plus will also get around that.  You'll need to log into PSN in order for that to work, though.  Using USB won't, though; savegames tend to be "signed" to the profile they were created with, and the system as well.  So things get tricky if PS Plus isn't an option.

Comment: What do you mean by backup saves? I copied mine to an external hdd using the "Saved data utility" from XMB

Comment: With a PS+ subscription, you can backup most saves to the cloud, even if they won't allow you to copy them to USB.  External HDDs will also work; so long as the saves allow it, anyways.

Comment: Well I dont have a PS+ subscription and don't plan on having one..

Comment: What you're doing will do the trick, as long as both the saves allow it, and your PS3 doesn't die.  Backing up and restoring saves onto the same PS3 is easy with unencrypted saves.  It gets a bit more complicated with encrypted saves, and really complicated when you're transferring them between PS3s.